# From convergence in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ to convergence in $L_\text{loc}^2(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis

[image][image]

the question is about convergence in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$  and $L^2_\text{loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ ... for details please look at the image i have attached above . Please let me know if there is something unclear to you . Thanks